# MySQL - Select the minimum value of a column after selecting the minimum value of another column, and be in a specific range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following Table (tablea):

```
   x            y
------------------------
   3            1
   1            4
   0            3
   0            1
```

I want x to be as low as possible as top priority, and y as low as possible as lower priority, also i want y to be in a certain range.
I want x=0 and y=3 as Output  and do following query:

```
Select x, MIN(y) AS y 
FROM tablea 
WHERE x = (SELECT MIN(x) FROM tablea where y between 2 AND 4);
```

It gives me x=0 and y=1 as Output (I understand why, but i don't know how to fix my query to get what i want).

Comment: So is your top priority actually finding a `y` between 2 and 4, then? I'm not sure your order of priority is clear in that regard...

Comment: @praguian Yeah you are right,  y in a certain range is my top priority, then x as low as possible, then y as low as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best way is to

```
SELECT x, y
FROM tablea 
WHERE y BETWEEN 2 AND 4
ORDER BY x, y LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select x, MIN(y) AS y 
FROM tablea 
WHERE x = (SELECT MIN(x) FROM tablea where y between 2 AND 4)
and y between 2 AND 4;
```